# How to disable auto detect datatype in azure data flow

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory

I was working on a XML file in ADF and there is a field that is having 42 integer digits. I want it to be reflected as it is in azure data flow so that I could perform some transformations
There is a checkbox "Detect Data Type" in copy data activity which when unchecked provides the exact value.
but when using the dataflow, it is not giving any option to not to perform auto detect data type .
kindly suggest what need to be done

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <start>
       <name>ABC</name>
       <id>123456789098765432123456789098765432123456</id>
   </start>
```

Comment: Oh my... please don't take pictures of the screen with a camera. At least use screenshots.

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Comment: Thank you so much.. This was really helpful and solved my problem. but in my case, it is a complex XML and flatten activity need to be performed after the source. I am not able to do so without the projection. Kindly guide

Comment: you can have `derived column` with `expression` using function `toString()` to convert that column data type to string in later steps. checkout the snips [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiRgO.png) and [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VXuk.png)

Comment: refer doc [Expression functions in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions)

Comment: Thanks @KarthikBhyresh-MT . but when we are using toString() in the later steps we are losing the originality of that data. It is again reflecting as a scientific notation.  data size is huge and XML file has multiple hierarchy as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import projection** from the **Projection tab** is used to Import schema and **detect data types** from the source. If you just don't click it or use this, your data columns will be of type string.

Here is an example:

**Source XML:**

[image]

**Import projections:**

> You can see the column `id` is inferred as type `Double`

[image]

[image]

**While if you just don't use Import projection option, and *Reset Schema***

> you get the column `id` as type `String`

[image]

For further details, refer official MS doc on [ADF Dataflow Projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#projection)