# How to load 20 digit number data in xml file into azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure data factory. I have one xml file with below data 1234567890.1234567890123456789
I have to load this data. But ADF truncating this number.

Please help me on this.

I tried with all possible data type like float, string, decimal but it's not working.

Comment: What is your destination[sink] table column data type?

Comment: It is String data type.

Comment: If your db is SQL Server, then you can make that column as `decimal(38,20)` to store 20 digits after decimal point.

Comment: In the Copy data activity, under data type conversion, you need to set `allowDataTruncation` to false, by default it is set to true.  See the official doc [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping)

Comment: My db server is picking the files from blob storage.

Comment: I am creating a data flow where  the source is  xml file. I am not using any copy activity

Comment: see if this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71091380) of similar thread helps you.